# How can I make comment model with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm making a website that uses mongoose, passportjs and nodejs. I want to add a comment functionality but I don't know how to make the comment model.

I already created my photos model, user model(this model works with passportjs) and comment model. But then I didn't know what to do.

I want user to write their own comment which my users can and when adds a comment I want to show username automatically on comments section with 'req.user.username' but I want this username to be saved in database

Comment: Create a comment model with the attributes you want like name ,text ,date etc.What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to get the username of the current User and save this to the database

Comment: in passport you get it by `req.user.username` if you have implemented it right

Comment: I did that and I know that. I want to save this to database. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a separate model for comments. Reason being, Comment count may go up to thousands and even more than that, if you maintain an array, it will not be easy to maintain and will be slow as well.

Even, if you create a new model for comment, it will help you in pagination as well. Your **commentSchema** model may contain:

1. PostRefId
2. comment
3. commentBy
4. createdAt
5. updatedAt
6. isDeleted
7. count  so on.